# How do I interpret this non-significant simple moderation analysis?

Tags: regression, data-visualization, interaction

I've performed a simple moderation analysis (model 1) using PROCESS v3.5 . My Dependent Variable is **Y**, my Independent Variable is **X**, and my 'moderator' is **M**. All my variables are continuous.

PROCESS Output:

The model summary was significant (p<.001).
The effects of X were significant (p<.05).
The effects of M were also significant (p<.001).
The interaction effect (X * M) was NON-significant (p = .472)

So I'm assuming this means that M does NOT moderate the relationship between X and Y.

I've also attached the output for the simple slopes of this analysis.

[image]

I'm really inexperienced with this type of analysis, so my question is how do I interpret this output? What do these "parallel" simple slopes imply?

Comment: It means that the effect (slope) of X on Y depends little on the particular value of M.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that there is no moderation effects taking place in your data. Only the main effects, $X$ and $M$ are related to $Y$ while the interaction effect $X*M$ is not.